# facebook Graph 2.1 - grabbing geotagged status messages and related data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation

Im just learning the FB Graph API and using Graph API Explorer.

My aim:
 - Get a list of all my status updates that have geolocation, the message, picture and tagged individuals

**Via Feed endpoint -** `me/feed?fields=message,picture,place,with_tags,name`

- I get items from my feed not posted by me
- Some of my posts are missing info, for example I have a [picture post](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=10154607762415137&version=v2.1) and the message for the picture is appearing in the objects field called "name" and not "message" as expected. Via Feed endpoint I can access the field "picture" but not "name" for this object.

**Via Statuses endpoint -** `me/statuses?fields=message,place,tags`

- I have whole posts missing from me, its appears to be all status updates with photos. But, posts with multiple images do appear.
- Cannot access the "picture" field from this endpoint

**Via tagged_places endpoint -** `me/tagged_places`

- Looks promising as this displays all locations the user is tagged in, but(!) I cannot access any fields relating to the object the user has posted (message,picture,etc)
- I even cannot get the ID of the object so that I could call it independently to grab the required fields

I am confident none of this is a permission issue, as with at least one example of the above I can access all data via the Graph, I just cannot do so in one call.

Any suggestions or advice would be very appreciated. (Sorry if I have gotten any terminology wrong)

Many thanks,
tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed/#read you should be able to use

```
GET /me/feed?fields=message,picture,place,with_tags,name&with=location
```

to get a list of Posts containing a geo location.

Comment: thanks Tobi, only just seen your post.
Completely missed this in the docs, unfortunately it still drops some posts that have location. No idea why, if you compare a missing post to one that works all data is there. Think ill have to make do with 'me/posts?fields=message,picture,place,with_tags,name' and filter out the non geo posts